# MySQL compare expiry time stamp with current time NOW()

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to check my expiry date with current time using NOW() function

Process:
I am adding reminder date time with jQuery UI Date time picker and its giving me time stamp like this ***2015-07-9 14:36*** it does not have any seconds but my created_at contain complete Unix time stamp.

But using the below command doesn't give me any result. MySQL date time set with PC date and time.

**MySql Code:**

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_web_contact_signups` WHERE `expiry` = NOW()
```

**Database:**

```
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
| ID |      expiry     |     created_at      |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2015-07-9 14:36 | 2015-07-01 11:22:24 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|  2 | 2015-07-9 14:38 | 2015-07-01 11:22:24 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|  3 | 2015-07-9 14:40 | 2015-07-01 11:22:24 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|  4 | 2015-07-9 14:50 | 2015-07-01 11:22:24 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Expiry column type **varchar**

**PS:** i am creating reminders and want to check how many reminders i have today or this time.

Comment: where is your expiration column?

Comment: Question edited, column name changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now() means current datetime, do you really have entry for current datetime, please check..

For check remonders of today use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_web_contact_signups` WHERE date(`expiry`) = CURDATE();
```

For check reminders of today and current hour use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_web_contact_signups` WHERE date(`expiry`) = CURDATE() and hour(`expiry`) = hour(now());
```

For check reminders of today and current hour and current minute use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_web_contact_signups` WHERE date(`expiry`) = CURDATE() and hour(`expiry`) = hour(now()) and Minute(`expiry`)=minute(now());
```

Comment: now() isnt a mysql function which returns the current date and time ?

Comment: yes it is, but your query compares the data in table..
means the table must have some rows with current date and time..
otherwise how the mysql returns data ?
you are comparing expiry in mysql table with current date / time

Comment: exactly i don need seconds i need date, hr and minutes please write a query

Comment: is there any query which check first only today all reminders and then which nearly to current time show as asc or desc wise?

Comment: i want to show all reminders in my page and on the only those which are nearly to expiry.

Comment: i dont want only today i want all.. can you write down the query i am newbie to mysql

Comment: SELECT * FROM `tbl_web_contact_signups` order by expiry desc.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_web_contact_signups WHERE  expiry = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%m') ;
```

You must have record in expiry column with that particular time(minute) of query firing.

or just check records for today with

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_web_contact_signups WHERE  DATE(expiry) = CURDATE();
```

Comment: @hy_sultani  try my first query